# How to set the Default Value of Today to a Radzen DatePicker that is already bound?

Tags: c#, blazor, radzen

I have a Radzen Datepicker in a Blazor Application:

```
<RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value=@WIR40Entity.DateIssued Placeholder=@DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString()  DateFormat="d" Change=@(args => OnChangeOrder(args, "DatePicker", "MM/dd/yyyy", )) Class="w-100" />
```

Right now, when a user clicks the DatePicker, it opens up to the current month and year.  But, I want the Datepicker to automatically highlight today's date (like their online demo).

So far, everything I have read uses the '@bind-Value=' to set today's date.

But how do you do that, when the date picker is already bound to a field from your model?

```
@bind-Value=@WIR40Entity.DateIssued
```

In this scenario, the user is creating a new record.

Comment: Simply: `WIR40Entity.DateIssued = DateTime.Now` either in your component or in your constructor of the object

Comment: Ahhhhh . . . . this was perfect.  Feeling kinda stupid now lol.  THANK YOU.